# Haml: Avoid extra-space when word wrapping

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

When I use Haml in my Rails view, word wrapping (especially to add italic or strong effect) display is rendered as a space. For example:

```
%p
    Click on "
    %em New Product
    " to add a product in your catalog.
```

Displays `Click on " New Product " to add a product in your catalog.` which contains extra spaces inside quotes.

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write this way.

```
%p
  Click on "
  %em> New Product
  " to add a product in your catalog.
```

[More](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#whitespace_removal__and_).

Comment: Excellent Michael: It's exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Another, more readable solution:

```
%p
  Click on "<em>New Product</em>" to add a product in your catalog.
```